# Multiple tables join in SQL for this scenario

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table structure 
I have 3 tables:

1. member table
2. comments table
3. comments like table

The tables structures can be found in the following images:

Table: member

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
user_id |full_name |email   | password  | image     |join_date     |
        |          |        |           |           |            |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table: album_comments

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
id |album_id |comment_text | comment_userid | post_date |active_bit |
   |         |             |                |           |     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table: comment_likes

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
id |user_id  |comment_id   | post_date      |           | like_bit  |
   |         |             |                |           |     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to join three tables and retrieve the result. Here is what I need:

I want to return latest 20 comments and check if the member who is currently logged in has liked any of the comment in these 20 comments. If yes then return status bit as 1 for those comments and if not then return status bit 0.

Can anyone tell what would be the SQL query for this?

Comment: You should remove the links and update the question with a simple ASCII table. Sample data and expected output would considerably help. BTW, what have you tried?

Comment: @user1884413 .. Please provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work for you. Select required columns from album_comments join it with comment_likes based on comment_id and check if the comment_likes user_id is equal to the user_id you sent from UI. ORDER BY DESC will return latest comments with LIMIT of 20.

```
Select |ac.Column1, ac.Column2...ac.Column-n|, cl.like_bit
FROM album_comments ac INNER JOIN comment_likes cl
ON ac.id = cl.comment_id AND cl.user_id = |screen user_id|
ORDER BY ac.id DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: For like_bit you should toggle between 0 and 1 while liking(insert new record) and disliking(update record).